# I want to find that how much number of products sold for particular category in northwind database?

Tags: sql

I have three main Tables

**`categories`**:

- `categoryID`(primary Key)
- `CategoryName`
- `Description`.

**`OrderDetails`**

- `OrderID` (primary Key)
- `ProductID`
- `Quantity`

**`Products`**

- `productId` (Primary Key)
- `ProductName`
- `CategoryID`

Now I have to write a query to get number of products sold for particular category?

here is my attempt

```
SELECT Products.ProductID,
       Products.CategoryID,
       SUM(OrderDetails.Quantity)

FROM   Products 

LEFT INNER JOIN OrderDetails 
  ON (SELECT OrderDetails.Quantity,
             orderDetails.ProductID,
             categories.categoryName 
      FROM   orderDetails 
      LEFT INNER JOIN Categories 
        ON categories.categoryID=products.CategoryId
      ) 
  ON Products.ProductId = OrderDetaqils.ProductId
```

i am not getting any answer close to my requirement.its not correct 
please give me the solution if possible

It would be great help if you can give me the solution. If you required any additional details please let me know

Comment: i need following columns in return   CategoryID,CategoryName,ProductID,TotalSoldAmount

Comment: @user3074104 you can edit you question instead of adding comment

Comment: sorry guys for the inconvenience but i am just a beginner to Sql

Comment: Please tell us which DBMS you are using. Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @user3074104 First, there is no such thing as a `LEFT INNER JOIN` - it is either a `LEFT JOIN` or an `INNER JOIN` that you want.  You are also missing a `GROUP BY` on your columns in the final SELECT list.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think since it is Northwind, it would be SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

here is the SQL query

```
SELECT Product.ProductID, 
       sum(Quantity) as TotalSoldAmount, 
       categories.CategoryID,
       CategoryName

FROM OrderDetails

-- INNER JOIN over all 3 Tables
INNER JOIN Product ON Product.ProductID = OrderDetails.ProductID
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.CategoryID = Product.CategoryID

-- we need to group our result because we used sum()
GROUP BY categories.CategoryID,
         CategoryName,
         Product.ProductID
```

and her the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/38a7f/2) as prove

Comment: Thank a lot for the help. I got my answer.  See u soon with new queries :D